# jQuery tab CSS conflicting with jQuery menu on page

Tags: jquery, css

I added a jQuery menu tab to my page and there is a clash in the CSS, as can be seen here: http://newbie-cms.com/demo1.

I separated a page with only the jQuery tabs here: http://newbie-cms.com/demo1/channeltabs  and that works fine. Also, the http://newbie-cms.com/demo1/index.html page works fine without the tabs.

But once I combine the tabs code with the videos page, the `ul,li` items of the tabs become displaced.

Where, in my CSS, can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Check your class assignments.

For example, based on your functioning menu, the ul element should have classes `ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all` and li elements should have classes `ui-state-default ui-corner-top`

Answer (score 0):

Your head is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<title>Mega Drop Down Menu</title>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style>
body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}
#menu li .drop {background:url("img/drop.gif") no-repeat right 8px; 
</style>
<![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            event: "mouseover"
        });
    });
    </script>

<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
  </script>

</head>
```

Here you see that you are calling $("#tabs").tabs() twice AND you have a javascript error because this code block

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
</script>
```

is executed BEFORE jQuery is loaded.
You have to fix this first...

Comment: Thanks GerjanOnline. I saw that I was calling this before the Jquery was loaded so i moved the jquery external calling link tag above this calling script for<code><script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
</script>
</code> :. I also see the two css files: menu.css and jquery-ui.css files that kurttheviking mentioned with the classes.

Comment: . I also see the two css files: menu.css and jquery-ui.css files that kurttheviking mentioned with the classes. Just not sure how to edit and add the classes needed.Thanks for your patience.